# Checking if a mysql row is NOT in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, where-clause

I know that you can use

```
WHERE `age` IN ($ages)
```

to find rows where the column `age` equals a part of an array.

But what i need to find out is - What if you want to find rows where `age` is NOT in the array??

thanks

Comment: Can't you just do `WHERE `age` NOT IN ($ages)`

Answer (score 10):

You need `NOT IN`.  Yep, it really is that simple.

```
$ages = "1,3,4,7,9";

// Your SQL WHERE clause...
WHERE `age` NOT IN ($ages)
```